# Docker image extending the mysql image isn't running the initdb scripts

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

Documentation for the [mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) docker image says:

> When a container is started for the first time [...] it will execute files with extensions .sh and .sql that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed data.

So at first I did this in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - .:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:ro
```

When I ran `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` the container was created and the sql files in the current directory were executed. So far all good.

But if I want to deploy these containers to another machine (using `docker-machine`), mounting `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` as a volume won't work, since that machine won't have access to my machine's `.` directory.

So then I tried to extend the `mysql:5.7` image:

```
FROM mysql:5.7
COPY ./*.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

And do this in my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

However, when I then run `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` on the second machine and try to run my application, **the `*.sql` files in the current directory aren't executed**. None of my tables are created.

Why doesn't my second approach work?

**EDIT:**
Ah, wait. I have asked the wrong question. The problem is not that the second approach doesn't work, it is that the second approach doesn't work when running it on the local docker-machine running in Virtualbox. The second approach actually works when I use it on my host machine (i.e. not using docker-machine).

Comment: Can you post the logs for when the container runs for the first time? What you have looks good, it is probably something simple.

Comment: Ah, wait. I have asked the wrong question. The problem is not that the second approach doesn't work, it is that the second approach doesn't work when running it on the local `docker-machine` running in Virtualbox. The second approach actually works when I use it on my host machine (i.e. not using `docker-machine`).

Comment: Ok, can you update the question, and it would still be good to see the logs, to see what is going on. It will only run the .sql scripts the very first time the container is started, so if you have added scripts after first run, they will not get run.

Comment: I found the issue. The problem was that I thought `docker-compose rm -f` destroyed any volumes attached to the containers, but I was wrong. So what I thought was the first `up`:ed containers were in fact using the database created by an earlier `up`. So the sql-files weren't run because it wasn't actually the first time the containers started. Duh. Thanks Ken for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Interesting behaviour of compose. I believe -v is meant to remove all volumes associated with the compose containers (if they were created by compose). Is this a bug Ken or does -v only remove 'named' containers?

Comment: Yes `docker-compose rm -v` will remove volumes for that container but `docker-compose rm -f` will not, which is what they did.

Comment: Although in his answer his sees the following behaviour: "Turns out that not even using docker-compose rm -v removes the volumes. I had to list them with docker volume ls and then remove them manually with docker volume rm <volume>" ?

Comment: At first I just used `-f` which didnt remove volumes and shouldnt remove volumes. Then I tried `-v` which still didnt remove volumes. Maybe I'm just missing something, I'm not very experienced with docker. Anyway, `docker volume rm <volume>` did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The problem was that I thought `docker-compose rm -f` destroyed any volumes attached to the containers, but I was wrong. So what I thought was the first up:ed containers were in fact using the database created by an earlier up. So the sql-files weren't run because it wasn't actually the first time the containers started. Duh. Thanks Ken for pointing me in the right direction.

Turns out that not even using `docker-compose rm -v` removes the volumes. I had to list them with `docker volume ls` and then remove them manually with `docker volume rm <volume>`.

Answer (score 0):

Another Docker-specific way to clean up volumes:

`docker system prune`

This will remove dangling images, containers, volumes, and networks. Adding `-a` will also remove expired containers and currently unused images.